# Chrome webRequest responseBody (POST) error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension and trying to log some requests: **the ones with POST parameters (plain text data)**

This is the code I'm using:

```
var requestFilter = {urls: ["<all_urls>"]};
var extraInfoSpec = ['requestHeaders','requestBody','blocking']; // note: without 'requestBody' it works perfectly, but there's no POST data available.
var handler = function( details ) {
    console.log(details);
};
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(handler, requestFilter, extraInfoSpec);
```

I use `requestHeaders` and `blocking` for other things that are not in the example (don't worry about them now)

I am getting this error at page load: `Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 2. Property '.1': Value must be one of: [requestHeaders, blocking].`

I am develping under Chrome **Version 36.0.1985.125 m**

Form chrome webRequest documentation: `Stable since Chrome 23. Contains the HTTP request body data. Only provided if extraInfoSpec contains 'requestBody'.`

**Any experience with this error? Any known solution? How can I solve this?**

Comment: The code you posted - is it in the background page or the content page?

Comment: It's in functions.js (called from manifest in "scripts" param)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are listening to the wrong event.

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeSendHeaders), `onBeforeSendHeaders` does not list `requestBody` in the callback details.

It is, however, available in `onBeforeRequest`.

So, if you need both the headers and the body, you have to correlate the two events by `requestId`.